# $ T^2=T_0 \iff R(T) \subseteq N(T) $. How is it possible? Contradiction.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

1) There is excersise 11 in chapter 2.3 of the book "Linear algebra" by Friedberg. In the excersise is stated:

> Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be linear. Prove that $ T^2 = T_0 $ 
>   if and only if $ R(T) \subseteq N(T) $.

$T_0$ is a zero transfomation.

The proof of the statement is below.

> If $T^2 = T$ we may pick y ∈ R(T) and thus we have y = T(x) for some
>    x and $T(y) = T(T(x)) = T^2(x) = 0$. Hence we conclude that y ∈ N(T).
>    Conversely if we have R(T) ⊂ N(T), we have $T^2(x) = T(T(x)) = 0$ since
>    T(x) is an element in R(T) and hence in N(T).

I've taken this proof from "Solutions to Linear Algebra" by Friedberg.

So $T^2 = T_0 \iff  R(T) \subseteq N(T) $. Let's not it as statement 1.

2) But we know that kernel and image are orthogonal subspaces and that they have only one interception in the origin. Let's consider the transformation A drawn below
[image: kernel and image]

I took the image from this article http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Kernel_of_linear_operator . We see the one dimentional kernel and the two dimentional image, they're orthogonal. So the first statement is impossible.

Let's note it as statement 2.

We see that statement 1 and statement 2 are conflicting. How to understand this contradiction?

Comment: What gave you the idea that image and kernel of an operator are orthogonal? For most spaces, orthogonality isn't even defined.

Comment: @faceless wanderer: What is $T_0$?

Comment: $T_0$ is a zero transformation. I'll add it in the question.

Comment: There's a typo or something - what you say can't be true, because there's nothing about $T_0$ in the right side of the equivalence.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer. I can't imagine a linear transformation with the kernel and the image that aren't orthogonal. Could you show me an example?

Comment: Take the linear map given by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Its kernel and image are the same space, the subspace spanned by $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null-space is a subset of the domain, the range is a subset of the codomain. In other words, for general transformations, $\ker(T)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ aren't even in the same space. How could they possibly be orthogonal in such a setting? I think your problem is that you confuse the domain of a transformation with its codomain - even if they are the same space, it's a different concept. $\ker (T)$ is "what you have to plug into $T$ in order to get $0$ as output" and $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is "what you can get out of $T$ if you can put everything into it".

For the actual task at hand, assume $\mathrm{Im}(T)\subset \ker(T)$ and let $y = Tx \in \mathrm{Im}(T)$. Then clearly
$$T^2 x = Ty = 0$$
since the image is inside the kernel.

The other way around can be easily proven by contradiction. Let $y\in \mathrm{Im}(T) \setminus \ker(T)$ and $Tx = y$ (this works since $y\in\mathrm{Im}(T)$. Then by assumption
$$0 = T^2 x = Ty \neq 0$$
since we assumed $y\notin\ker(T)$. Thus we arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, it was my problem. But how to call non kernel columns? Are they basis in every matrix?

Comment: @facelesswanderer Usually a column of a matrix will be a linear combination of a kernel element and a non-kernel element, i.e.
$$a = a_0 + a_+$$
With $a_0 \in \ker T$ and $a_+ \in (\ker T)^\perp$. And you can only be sure that the columns of a matrix span the image of the associated transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if $R(T)\subset N(T)$ then for $x \in R(T)$, we have $T(x)=0$. So $T(R(T))$ ={$T(x): x \in R(T)$}=$0$.

And there is ultimately no conflict. If the map is $0$ then $N(T)=V$ and $R(T)=$ {$0$}, and the $0$ vector is orthogonal to the whole space.